# Is there a way to save accelerometers data when the iPhone is locked in React-native

Tags: ios, database, react-native, accelerometer

Trying to save some accelerometers data in my APP, but when the phone is locked. It dont save. I need to save this data in real-time in react-native.

Already tried use Realm, but it crashes.

Comment: Maybe this [article](https://blog.expo.io/how-to-run-background-tasks-in-react-native-e1619acef48f) will offer you some help :)

Comment: Can you define your problem more accurately? While screen is locked, app is in background. Is your problem **1.** Background execution in react-native **2.** Getting accelerometer reading while in background mode **3.** Saving to realm (with assumption that you are able to execute code in background with react-native, and 'get' accelerometer data). Accordingly, the answer will differ completely.